# FileStream changes excel extension

Tags: c#, excel

The code opens filestream to save an excel file from the embedded resources. This file is then moved to the save location on the server and has to be opened.

It gives the following error

> the file format and extension don't match

If you look in to the excel file it "Thinks" it is an **.xltx**

While everywhere in the code and in the original file it is **.xls**

This only happens on one computer all others do save and open it as .xls

Can I force the extension when saving or ignore the extension fault when opening?

```
saveLocationAndFileName = saveLocation + Order + "_" + Name + ".xls";
string TempfileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()+ ".xls";

Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Resources.04.06 Checklist.xls");
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(TempfileName, FileMode.CreateNew);
for (int i = 0; i < stream.Length; i++)
    fileStream.WriteByte((byte)stream.ReadByte());
fileStream.Close();

//move temp file to server and rename
File.Copy(TempfileName, saveLocationAndFileName);
//delete temp file
File.Delete(TempfileName);

Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
app.DisplayAlerts = false;
Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(saveLocationAndFileName, CorruptLoad: true);
```

Comment: Have you checked Excel settings on this machine? It could be configured to save documents as xltx by default.

Comment: But Excel is not saving the file, the StreamWriter does that.